# JSON only retrieve objects with specific parameter

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I've created this live update script which update the current matches every 5 seconds. However i would like to create a tab where you can choose different sports so therefor i need to be able to only retrieve objects where the key game is for instance equal to football. How can i create a kind of function or extra parameter in order to achieve this?

```
var lastLoadedMatch = 0,
ajaxInterval = 5000;

$(function() {
  getMatches();

});

function getMatches(lastId) {
$.getJSON('URL JSON', function(resp) {

  var matches = resp.live;
  if (lastId) {
    matches = matches.filter(function(match) {
      return match.id > lastId;
    });
  }

  if (matches.length) {
    $.each(matches, function(_, match) {

      if (match.match_id > lastLoadedMatch) {
        lastLoadedMatch = match.match_id
      }
      $('body').append(matchHtml(this))
    });

  }else{

  }

  setTimeout(function() {
      getMatches(lastLoadedMatch);
    }, ajaxInterval);




});
}


 function matchHtml(obj) {
 var team1 = obj['team 1'],
 team2 = obj['team 2'];
 var html = '<div class="match" data-id="' + obj.match_id + '">';
 html += '<h5>Match</h5>';
 html += '<p>Team 1 = ' + team1.name + ', bet = ' + team1.bet + '<br>';
 html += 'Team 2 = ' + team2.name + ', bet = ' + team2.bet + '</p>';
 html += '</div>';

 return html;

 }
```

Json

```
{
    "live": [
    {
        "match_id": "65551",
        "has_vods": false,
        "game": "hearthstone",
        "team 1": {
            "score": "",
            "name": "ViCi Gaming",
            "bet": "39%"
        },
        "team 2": {
            "score": "",
            "name": "ZhanQi TV",
            "bet": "61%"
        },
        "live in": "Live",
        "title": "ViCi Gaming... 39% vs 61% ZhanQi TV",
        "url": "",
        "tounament": "http://www.gosugamers.net/",
        "simple_title": "ViCi Gaming... vs ZhanQi TV",
        "streams": [
            "http://www.twitch.tv/widgets/live_embed_player.swf?channel=Curemew"
        ]
    },
    {
        "match_id": "64907",
        "has_vods": false,
        "game": "dota2",
        "team 1": {
            "score": "",
            "name": "Summoner's Rift",
            "bet": "19%"
        },
        "team 2": {
            "score": "",
            "name": "Thundercats!",
            "bet": "12%"
        },
        "live in": "Live",
        "title": "Summoner's Rift 19% vs 12% Thundercats!",
        "url": "",
        "tounament": "http://www.gosugamers.net/",
        "simple_title": "Summoner's Rift vs Thundercats!",
        "streams": [
            "http://www.majorleaguegaming.com/player/embed/joinDOTA?autoplay=0"
        ]
    }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I would suggest using $.POST with an array of data to the server, then using parseJSON on the response to give you JSON. That way the array is your filter/ option list

Comment: Could u make a question with a snippet, first time im using jquery and AJAX. best regards

Comment: Give me a few moments,, As only give limited time atm.

Comment: What does your JSON look like?

Comment: Hi Juan i've added a snippet of json

Answer (score 0):

Sorry as this is only a very quick example.. Hopefully someone who has more time can give you an extended example.

THE JS CODE

```
var myOptions = {name: "John", time: "2pm" };
$.post( "proc.php",myOptions    ).done(function( data ) {
    var oResult = $.parseJSON(data);
    alert( "Data Loaded: " + oResult );
});
```

**THE PHP CODE** proc.php

```
<?php
    $arrayResult = array();

    if (isset($_POST['name'])) {
        $arrayResult['name'] = $_POST['name'];
    }
    if (isset($_POST['time'])) {
        $arrayResult['time'] = $_POST['time'];
    }
    echo json_encode($arrayResult);

?>
```

By using the above logic, You simple adjust what is the js object and that will determine what the server side returns back to you.

By using POST, you can send an array or other types of data where as GET will only work with query string / normal url string.

Because post does not return JSON by default, simple parse the result as shown,

**THINKING ABOUT IT**
Are you wanting to filter your JS content, or the requested JSON content.
One would be server side, the other would be client side..

So depends on what you ideally want as the end result and the amount of data/time to filter.. But can apply this logic to your back end anyway.

Comment: But would this auto update without refreshing browser?

Comment: Where the alert code is, that is an event/callback that executes when javascript has received a response from the server. So you would place your code in there to work the data you got back from the server and change your html as required.. So it can update without refreshing the browser. $ajax, $.get, $.post $.getJSON are more or less the same, they all just work a little different in how they send or receive the data.

Comment: Not quite sure how to do this properly. So i create a js file with the js code and then a test.html with what and a php file with hte above php code?

Comment: Ah sorry, that was my bad.. the test.html should be a php file.. i've edited my answer with the changes.. basically the jquery post function sends its request/data to the proc.php file and then when ready, responds using the  .done function where the alert is..

Comment: but i dont guess that $_POST['name'] will update unless i refresh browser? when its php

Comment: The whole concept is if you need to query new data from the server/php, you use something like $.post or $.getJSON to send variables to php, your php script will process these variables in the background while your browser waits for php to respond / finish processing the file. You echo your content/results from PHP and the $.post function will give you the data that PHP had echoed. Same as $.getJSON reads a .json file, simply replacing it with a PHP file will make it a dynamic .json file..